# Masking part of event data in socketio room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Im working on a socket server built on socketio. My setup uses rooms in which all clients can perform actions that update a central state. The central state hold the data of all clients, i.e.

```
const state = [
   { "id": 1, "name": "John", "secret": "foo" },
   { "id": 2, "name": "Jane", "secret": "bar" } 
]
```

When a user updates the state, the socket will then broadcast the updated state to all connected clients. I.e.

```
socket.to(room).broadcast("update", state)
```

My goal is to mask certain values of the state, i.e. the secret values, per response per client. For client with id `1` I would ideally want to mask the secret value of client with id `1` and vice versa.

Is there a way to achieve this with `socket.io`? And if so, how could I achieve this? I have tried to find an answer but was unable to find any relevant information or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this one out myself. Happy to hear if you all agree with the solution.

If you want to individually handle the emitting to each individual client, you can do the following (assuming you know the room).

```js
const clients = await socket.in("<your_room>").fetchSockets();
const state = [
  { id: 1, name: "John", secret: "foo" },
  { id: 2, name: "Jane", secret: "bar" },
];

// Iterate over all clients in the room
clients.forEach((_socket, index) => {
  return _socket.emit(
    "update",
    state.map((entry) =>
      entry.id !== _socket.id ? { ...entry, secret: "**********" } : entry
    )
  );
});
```